# what are These ones mean ? it’s a Homework !

Tags: bash

[image: What are these points as shown in the pictures]

What are these points as shown in the pictures

Comment: Replace image by text.

Answer (score 3):

`.` is the current directory
`..` is the parent directory.

To hide those dirs, do :

```
ls -A
```